# Alternative for PSM package

Tags: package

Anyone could suggest an alternative for PSM package in R for parametric survival model since this package has been removed?

Answer (score 0):

psm() is a function within the rms package; can you clarify which psm package do you mean? 
the PSM package is here: https://rdrr.io/cran/PSM/

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I need the PSM package to fit parametric regression and perform selction of variable.For example; psm.lung<-psm(Surv(time,status)~ph.ecog+sex*age+ph.karno+pat.karno+meal.cal+weight.loss,dist='weilbull'). Then perform anova(psm.lung).

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce the results of the paper with the following codes:

> Zhang Z. Parametric regression modelfor survival data: Weibull
>   regression model as an example. Ann Transl Med 2016;4(24):484. doi:
>   10.21037/atm.2016.08.45

```
> install.packages("rms")
> library(rms)
> library(survival)
> data(lung)
> psm.lung<-psm(Surv(time, status)~ph.ecog+sex*age+
+                 ph.karno+pat.karno+meal.cal+
+                 wt.loss,lung, dist='weibull')
> anova(psm.lung)
                Wald Statistics          Response: Surv(time, status) 

 Factor                                   Chi-Square d.f. P     
 ph.ecog                                  13.86      1    0.0002
 sex  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)       10.24      2    0.0060
  All Interactions                         3.22      1    0.0728
 age  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)        3.75      2    0.1532
  All Interactions                         3.22      1    0.0728
 ph.karno                                  5.86      1    0.0155
 pat.karno                                 3.54      1    0.0601
 meal.cal                                  0.00      1    0.9439
 wt.loss                                   3.85      1    0.0498
 sex * age  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)  3.22      1    0.0728
 TOTAL                                    33.18      8    0.0001
```